# python gettext - produce an error when message id not found

Tags: python, python-2.7, gettext

I'm using python2.7 gettext.
For translation I use the following code:

```
t = gettext.translation(
            domain,
            path,
            fallback=False,
            languages=[self._lang, 'en']
        )
_ = t.ugettext
translated = _('foo')
```

The default behaviour is that if there is no entry in the catalog for the message id, the message id is returned.

Is there a way to produce an error instead?
**A simple code example would be appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible without hacking the source code of gettext. You could write a wrapper around the translation function that produces an error if the retrieved translation equals the message id but that will often result in false positives because it happens that the correct translation for a string is the string itself.

If you follow the normal translation workflow, such a feature is not necessary. When you compile the `.po` files with `msgfmt`, you can pass the option `--statistics` which will report missing translations. What is the point in checking that at run-time then?

Comment: Exactly what I did, only I wrote my own python script for checking the translations instead of using msgfmt

Comment: But does you script also implement `--check`? Formally incorrect translations should often be counted as missing.

Comment: See my solution below

Answer (score 2):

As [Guido Flohr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52115620/475472) suggested, I wrote my own script for checking the translations, but in python using [polib](https://pypi.org/project/polib/).

the translations folder tree is as follows:

[image]

`locale.json` contains the supported languages list (which gives me the option to place draft languages without testing them)

```
{"supported":["en","he"]}
```

This these are the 2 scripts (sorry for the bad indentation, I coulnd't make it work on StackOverflow):

```
import polib
def test_po_files_msgid_different_from_mgsstr():
errors_list = list()
msg_count = 0
po_files_count = 0
locale_path = os.path.join(BASE_PROJECT_PATH, 'locale')
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(locale_path):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith('.po'):
            po_file_path = os.path.join(root, f)
            po = polib.pofile(po_file_path)
            po_files_count += 1
            for entry in po:
                msg_count += 1
                if entry.msgid == entry.msgstr or entry.msgstr == '' or entry.msgstr is None:
                    errors_list.append(
                        "Error in {}: msgid '{}' equals its msgstr, empty or None".format(po_file_path, entry.msgid))
if po_files_count == 0:
    raise Exception('No po files found in {} and its subdirectories'.format(locale_path))

print('{} messages checked, in {} files'.format(msg_count, po_files_count))
if errors_list:
    errors_list_str = '\n'.join(errors_list)
    raise Exception(errors_list_str)


def test_po_files_on_secondary_lang_maches_en():
    """
    Compares supported languages consistency with the default language
    checks all domain (files) and msgids on the default language exists on the secondary one
    """
default_lang = 'en'

def get_supported_languages():
    file_path = os.path.join(BASE_PROJECT_PATH, 'locale', 'locale.json')
    with open(file_path) as json_data:
        dict_data = json.load(json_data)
        return dict_data['supported']

def validate_language(en_tree, curr_lang, curr_lang_tree):
    errors_list = list()
    for file in en_tree:
        if curr_lang_tree.get(file) == None:
            errors_list.append("Error in '{}': file '{}' doesn't exist".format(curr_lang, file))
            continue

        # if file == 'test_msgid_exist_only_in_en.po':
        for msgid in en_tree[file]:
            if not curr_lang_tree[file].get(msgid):
                errors_list.append(
                    "Error in '{}': msgid '{}' doesn't exist in file '{}', ".format(curr_lang, msgid, file))
    return errors_list

def create_lang_tree(locale_path):
    lang_tree = dict()
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(locale_path):
        for f in files:
            if f.endswith('.po'):
                lang = root.split('/')[-2]
                if not lang_tree.get(lang):
                    lang_tree[lang] = dict()
                lang_tree[lang][f] = dict()
                po_file_path = os.path.join(root, f)
                po = polib.pofile(po_file_path)
                for entry in po:
                    lang_tree[lang][f][entry.msgid] = entry.msgstr
    return lang_tree

locale_path = os.path.join(BASE_PROJECT_PATH, 'locale')
errors_list = list()
supported_languages = get_supported_languages()
lang_tree = create_lang_tree(locale_path)

if not lang_tree:
    raise Exception('No po files found in {} and its subdirectories'.format(locale_path))

en_tree = lang_tree[default_lang]
for curr_lang in supported_languages:
    if curr_lang == default_lang:
        continue
    curr_lang_errors = validate_language(en_tree, curr_lang, lang_tree[curr_lang])
    errors_list.extend(curr_lang_errors)

if errors_list:
    errors_list_str = '\n'.join(errors_list)
    raise Exception(errors_list_str)

print("{} secondary languages compared to 'en', no errors found".format(len(supported_languages) - 1))
```